# Size in mm of website mock up using InDesign

Tags: website-design

I want to create my website mock up using InDesign. Based on a  finished website resolution of 1024 x 768 what size should I create my pages in InDesign (in mm).

Thanks

Comment: Just an fyi: 1024 x 768 is extremely small resolution now. Six or seven years ago this was the average, or most used resolution, and thus, it was standard to design websites to fit 1024 x 768 and assume you were rendering okay on most computers. The explosion of laptop usage in the last five or so years briefly slowed the rate at which average screen size was increasing, so the standard of 1024 x 768 stuck around, but not for too long. Now deviced are so diverse in terms of small mobile devices and giant monitors, the 1024 x 768 rule is outdated.

Comment: Above comment continued.. It's not a bad idea to mock things up with a width of around 960 to 1000px and assume you're going to have margins on the side, but the idea of a fold at 768px is dated enough you shouldn't be mocking up sites with it that low.

Answer (score 4):

Why? Simply input 1024px for width and 768px for height. Indesign (Or any Adobe app) will accept whatever measurement you input. You can input 3", 3 in, 3cm, 3px, 3p0, 3mm... they will all be accepted by the dimension fields and then converted to whatever default dimension the rulers are set to. You don't need mm.

But if you really want mm... 
1024px x 768px = 361.244mm x 270.933mm

Be aware a pixel is **not** a unit of measurement, so the conversion is essentially based on the assumption that 1 pixel = 1 point. However, in reality pixels have no set width or heights.

Indesign is really a poor choice of tool in my opinion for web site layout. You'd be better served by using Illustrator or Photoshop.

Comment: I agree completely. Note that if the OP really wanted to do this, at the very least, the document should be in 4:3 aspect ratio

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: Curious about the 4:3 ratio as well. Why?